# Будьте чесними / Be honest

Tags: discussion, rules, admin-reference

… в тому сенсі, що відділяйте власну позицію/бажання від об'єктивної реальності.

Темою сайту є українська мова. Норми української мови регулюються словниками та правописом, що затверджуються Міністерством освіти і науки. Так, їхні рішення не є ідеальними (мабуть, кожен з нас має хоч один пункт, за яким він не згоден з офіційною позицією). Тим не менш вони повинні бути хоча б враховані при написанні відповіді, якщо саме запитання не стосується безпосередньо якогось неофіційного правопису / нестандартного діалекту / чиєїсь думки. Тобто не можна зосереджувати відповідь навколо неофіційного правопису / нестандартного діалекту / чиєїсь думки, не зазначаючи, якщо вони відрізняються від офіційної.

Припустимо, є запитання «Я правильно: *X* чи *Y*?» і офіційний правопис вимагає *X* або дозволяє обидва варіанти:

- Хороша відповідь: «Офіційний правопис каже *теє*, але…» — і далі можуть іти контраргументи, якщо бажаєте.
- Гірша (не факт, що повноцінна), але все ж чесна відповідь: «Я не знаю, що каже щодо цього офіційний правопис, але…».
- Погано: <s>«Правильно — *Y*…»</s> — це вводить користувача в оману.

---

… in the sense that you should make clear distinction between your wishes/opinions and objective reality.

The topic of the site is Ukrainian language. Norms of the Ukrainian language are regulated by dictionaries and official orthography issued by Ministry of Education and Science of Ukraine. Their decisions aren't always ideal (probably, any on us has at least one point of disagreement with official prescriptions). Still, they should not be ignored when writing an answer, unless the question itself asks about unofficial orthography / non-standard dialect / someone's opinion. I.e. you should not build your answer around unofficial orthography / non-standard dialect / someone's opinion (different from the official norm) without making it clear that official norm is different.

Assuming there is a question “Which one is correct: *X* or *Y*?” and official orthography prescribes to write *X* or allows both variants:

- Good: «Official orthography says *this*, but…» — and here your counterarguments can go, if you wish.
- Worse (probably, incomplete) but still honest answer: «I don't know what official orthography prescribes, but…».
- Bad: <s>«*Y* is correct…»</s> — that's deceives a reader.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an announcement, not a genuine question.